# There isn’t a setter named 'selection' in class 'TextEditingController'

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, selection, onchange

I'm try to keep the cursor on the right of the TextField input using the 'controller.selection' line with 'onChange' as shown below; but getting an error

```
onChanged: (text) {
_myController.text = text;
_myController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: 
_myController.text.length));
},
```

the error:

```
There isn’t a setter named 'selection' in class 'TextEditingController'.
Try correcting the name to reference an existing setter, or declare the setter.
```

I have used this method before with no issues but for some reason getting this now.

Comment: Why you are doing it manually, is there any specific  reason and code is correct I think., Can you include full sample widget that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by force upgrading the flutter sdk using `flutter upgrade --force` - before that it was not upgrading for some reason.

Probably I modified some system file or library that I was not supposed to modify, but now everything seems to be fine back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set both text and selection, you should set the [value](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/value.html) instead:

```
final selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: text.length));

_myController.value = TextEditingValue(text, selection);
```